# Print statement not printing anything on console in python

Tags: python, json, scripting

Print statement not printing anything on console in python.

- I am printing the key, value of the JSON file where the key starts with `@id`

  ```
  found = False

  for key, di in json.loads(json_data).iteritems():

    for k, v in di.items():

        if k.startswith('@id'):

             found = True

             print k, v

             sys.stout.flush()

             break

    if found:

       break
  ```

I think have done a mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem and provide any errors you're getting so that we can help you. You also have a typo because it is `stdout`, not `stout`. If you're using Python 3, `print` is a function and follows different syntax from Python 2. So, you need to write `print(k,v)` instead.

Comment: @VasilisG.  it is not printing the values of k,v it it printing as blank on the console.please help

Comment: Please provide some sample data of your json file.

Comment: @VasilisG.                                                                                                              {
    "nvd": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "@id": "CVE-2016-0001", 
                "vuln:cve-id": "CVE-2016-0001", 
                "vuln:published-datetime": "2017-05-11T10:29:55.767-04:00", 
                "vuln:last-modified-datetime": "2017-05-11T10:29:55.767-04:00", 
                "vuln:summary": "** REJECT **  DO NOT USE THIS CANDIDATE NUMBER. "
},

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample data you provided in the comment section, you can try this:

```
import json

json_data = '{ "nvd": { "entry": [ { "@id": "CVE-2016-0001", "vuln:cve-id": "CVE-2016-0001", "vuln:published-datetime": "2017-05-11T10:29:55.767-04:00", "vuln:last-modified-datetime": "2017-05-11T10:29:55.767-04:00", "vuln:summary": "** REJECT ** DO NOT USE THIS CANDIDATE NUMBER. " }]}}'

wantedKey = "@id"
found = False

for key, di in json.loads(json_data).items():
    if wantedKey in di['entry'][0]:
        found = True
        print(wantedKey + " : " + di['entry'][0][wantedKey])
        break
```

Output:

```
@id : CVE-2016-0001
```

Comment: ;it is giving error :    File "downloads.py", line 61, in <module>
    print (wantedKey + " : " + di['entry'][1][wantedKey])
NameError: name 'wantedKey' is not defined
Please help

Comment: You need to declare `wantedKey` first, as in the code, above the `found` variable.